# JavaFXPorts Kokos Project doesn't show the Android keyboard

Tags: android, javafx, javafxports

I am modifying the [kokos](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples/src/0baab224193a/Kokos/?at=default) project with JavaFX and Android, with the jfxmobile plugin and when I add a textfield the on-screen keyboard does not appear and I can not modify the text.

`mytextfield` is an object of the TextField class of JavaFX:

```
@FXML 
public void initialize(){ 
    counter = 0; 
    mytextfield.setStyle( "-fx-background-color:#FFFF00; -fx-skin: \"com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkinAndroid\"; ");
    mytextfield.requestFocus(); 
} 

public void onButtonClick(){ 
    counter++; 
    clickLabel.setText("You've clicked this button " + counter + " times!"); 
}
```

What could be happening?

Comment: Post some code of what you have tried, otherwise it is impossible to find out and we can't help you.

Comment: @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        counter = 0;
        mytextfield.setStyle( "-fx-background-color:#FFFF00; -fx-skin: \"com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkinAndroid\"; ");
                mytextfield.requestFocus();
    }

    public void onButtonClick(){
        counter++;
        clickLabel.setText("You've clicked this button " + counter + " times!");
    }
}

Comment: mytextfield is an object of the TextField class of javafx. When I run the code with the jfxmobile plugin on android it does not show the keyboard when I click on the text field.

Comment: Edit your question and post the code there, not in the comments. By the way, there is no need for setting the skin of the textfield. I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: It is the project kokos of the link https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples/src, changing the label control by the textfield control javafx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the [Kokos](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples/src/0baab224193a/Kokos/?at=default) project, modifying the JavaFX [application](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples/src/0baab224193a903026cf9eb3a1a816c28d298d81/Kokos/app/src/main/java/javafxports/org/kokos/MyFxApp.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) class to include a JavaFX `TextField`:

```
@Override
public void start (Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final Button b = new Button("Click JavaFX");
    b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            b.setText("Clicked");
        }
    });
    Screen primaryScreen = Screen.getPrimary();
    Rectangle2D visualBounds = primaryScreen.getVisualBounds();
    double width = visualBounds.getWidth();
    double height = visualBounds.getHeight();

    VBox box = new VBox(10, b, new TextField());
    box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Scene s = new Scene(box, width, height);
    stage.setScene(s);
    stage.show();
}
```

and I can reproduce the issue: the soft keyboard doesn't show up.

[image]

For starters you don't need to set the `-fx-skin` property for the TextField, it will be applied internally.

If you check the logs, with `adb logcat` or from AndroidStudio, you will notice that there is a call to show the keyboard when the textField gets the focus, and another one to hide it when it loses it:

```
V/FXEntity: Called notify_showIME
V/FXEntity: Done calling notify_showIME
...
V/FXEntity: Called notify_hideIME
V/FXEntity: Done Calling notify_hideIME
```

This means that the JavaFX TextField actually do the right calls to show and hide the keyboard, but something is failing.

After some debugging, I noticed that the [activity_main.xml](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples/src/0baab224193a903026cf9eb3a1a816c28d298d81/Kokos/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#activity_main.xml-9) was using this for the fragment definition:

```
android:name="android.webkit.WebViewFragment"
```

which corresponds with a built-in fragment intended to show a WebView.

That is not what we need here, so I created a fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fx_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

based on the existing `fx_fragment.xml`, and modified `activity_main.xml` accordingly:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="javafxports.org.kokos.MyFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    tools:layout="@layout/fx_fragment" />
```

And this is it, now when you run the app and the textField gets the focus, the keyboard shows up, and you can type in it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I had been trying to solve the problem for a long time. Works!!!!!!! How can I rate?

Comment: Probably others may have faced it too. The sample should be updated properly.